# I have two questions about formatting a definition in latex/beamer. Please run the short document below

Tags: beamer, header-footer

```
\documentclass[ aspectratio = 1610 ]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usetheme{Frankfurt}  
\usecolortheme{wolverine} 
\begin{document}  
\def\myemph{\textcolor [rgb]{.7,1,1 }}  . \bigskip 
\begin{definition} [\myemph{1. How do I get this text to appear in standard italics ? }  \\ 
 2. Also, is it possible to have this definition (with only a header) omit the white bar below?]
 \end{definition}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: A beamer document without frame environments does not really make sense. If you want to use beamer in order to create the slides for a presentation, enclose contents that belong to the same slide in a frame environment.

Comment: There is many problems in your code. Starting by your second problem, your white bar in your definition block appears because the body of the block is empty. You are just adding everything in the title of the definition.

Comment: And about the coloring, I couldn't follow which part you want to color? The definition title, the background, the text, the body, etc?

Comment: I don't understand your first request. Your newly defined command `\myemph` just changes the text color. In your first qustion you ask about text in "standard italics". Why not simply use `\textit{...}` here?

Comment: Probably a sketch of the desired output would help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer (as I couldn't comment it) but rather to show you how to basically start using the beamer, frames and blocks. As @leandriis has mentioned you have to use     `\begin{frame}` to create a new slide and you may use `\frametitle` to add a title for this slide . Also, the `definition` block should have a body and you can optionally place a title for it in a square brackets like this `[Definition Term]` and then you may italics it or not .

About the coloring you need to be more specific about what you want to color. Generally speaking you can use `\setbeamercolor` command then adding the name of the block and the color of your choice of the background and foreground.

This is a minimal code (based on your example) you can start with:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio = 1610]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide title}
    \begin{definition}[\textit{Definition Term}]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item How do I get this text to appear in standard italics ?
            \item Also, is it possible to have this definition (with only a header) omit the white bar below?
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output you get is

[image]

Comment: Here is even a better introduction about how to use Beamer Presentations https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Beamer_Presentations:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Getting_Started

Comment: Thanks, Hesham.   I know how to write Beamer frame code. I was just  leaving out unnecessary code.

Comment: But here is my real question.  I inherited some theorem below and want to keep using it.

Comment: But  textit doesn't work. with the font or whatever that is being used.  So my questions are  1) What could I use instead of textit?  2. If I want a theorem box with text only in the header, is it possible o get only the heder to print, without the empty white content box below.